# What's wrong with the last line of my code?

Tags: php, function, oop, error-handling

The following code is for my University project. The last line has an error when I run as a web page ... I need help on how to solve this issue.

```
<?php
include_once 'ShapeClass.php';    
class Square extends Shape
      print "<h2>This square's side is not bigger than the parallelogram's height</h2>";
   }
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: It's not just the last line which has an error!

Comment: Why is that code not in a method? No wonder there is an error. You might want to put it in the constructor.

Answer (score 6):

The right way..

```
<?php
include_once 'ShapeClass.php';

class Square extends Shape
{
    function __construct()
    {
                print("<h2>This square's side is not bigger than the parallelogram's height</h2>");
    }
}
```

---

#### The mistakes you did

- There was an unnecessary `break` statement.
- You can't directly `print` as it is inside the class. You need to wrap that in a method.
- You forgot open a `{` after your `class`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class Square extends Shape {
     function __construct() {
            print "<h2>This square's side is not bigger than the parallelogram's   height</h2>";
 }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the braces in your code, it looks quite haphazard.

```
include_once 'ShapeClass.php';

class Square extends Shape
{
    print "&lt;h2>This square's side is not bigger than the parallelogram's height&lt;/h2>";
    break;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with this.  First, a class code block is in the form

```
class MyClass extends OtherClass {
    // code for MyClass goes here
}
```

You don't even have an opening curly brace.

Second, there should not be arbitrary code placed inside of a class.  Thus, the `print_r()` should not be placed directly inside the curly braces.

Third, if you are trying to stop execution, the `break` is incorrect in context.  Since it is also arbitrary code, it should not be placed directly inside the curly braces.  Also, it should probably be `exit()`.

I suggest reading 3 chapters on object oriented programming from Larry Ullman's book, http://www.larryullman.com/books/php-advanced-and-object-oriented-programming/.  Also, you might consider reading up on the fundamentals of object oriented php https://www.php.net/oop5.basic.